# Authentication error while removing windows using os uninstaller

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall

So I chose to remove windows using OS uninstaller and my laptop screen is locked, and when I try to login as usual, it does not let me type my password. It says 'authentication error' straight away. I am so lost. What do I do?

Comment: There is this help page. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller

Comment: @David yea I followed those steps and while installing, my login screen is blank

Comment: At the bottom of that page is the link to the official site, have you looked there?

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of all do Control+Alt+F1, this will put you in CLI (Command Line Interface) like DOS it will ask for your ubuntu login password the one you made while installing ubuntu or made another account afterwards (it needs root privileges) type the username hit enter type the password (it will show blank, you wont be able to see what password you typed) then run the following command: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` This shuold fix it if it does'nt try booting up from a ubuntu live cd/dvd or usb